# Inner join on tables with 50M and 30K entries

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-11

I have two tables A and B. A contains 50 million entries and B contains just 30 thousand. I have created default indexes (B-tree) on the columns used to join the tables. The join field is of type `character varying`.

I am querying the database with this query:

```
SELECT count(*)
from B INNER JOIN A
   ON B.id = A.id;
```

The execution time of the above query is approximately 8 seconds. When I saw the execution plan, the planner applies a sequential scan to table A scanning all the 50 million entries (this is taking most of the time) and an index scan on table B.

How can I speed up the query?

Comment: Did you run `analyze` on both tables?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for both tables and all `create index` statements together with the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. Or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: If `B.id` is a foreign key then you could also write it like `SELECT count(*) FROM B WHERE id IS NOT NULL` which should slightly faster, depending on your ratio of total vs. criteria count.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot speed up this query if you want an exact result.

The most efficient join strategy will probably be a hash or merge join, depending on your `work_mem` setting.

You *might* be able to get some speed improvement with an index only scan; try to `VACUUM` both tables before querying.

The only tuning method would be to make sure both tables are cached in RAM.

There are ways to get estimated counts, see [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/count-made-fast/) for details.

Comment: Read your blog. Thanks for the help!